# How to change the default path assets are served in SvelteKit?

Tags: vite, sveltekit

I created a sample app using SvelteKit to perform SSR. I noticed the svelte assets are always downloaded following this path  `_app/immutable/..` (examples):

```
http://localhost:3000/_app/immutable/start-9080d3a7.js
http://localhost:3000/_app/immutable/chunks/index-cad423a5.js
http://localhost:3000/_app/immutable/layout.svelte-eb403b25.js
http://localhost:3000/_app/immutable/pages/up-homeui/index.svelte-d6a3b39b.js
http://localhost:3000/_app/immutable/error.svelte-3f23e1a2.js
```

How can I serve the assets at the root level, like:

```
http://localhost:3000/start-9080d3a7.js
http://localhost:3000/index-cad423a5.js
http://localhost:3000/layout.svelte-eb403b25.js
http://localhost:3000/index.svelte-d6a3b39b.js
http://localhost:3000/error.svelte-3f23e1a2.js
```

At the end, I would like to serve all the files at the same level.

I already played with the svelte.config and the vite.config but I couldn't find a way to change this default behavior.